# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request while using LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using LINQ expressions to filter what data I want to recieve from database.
Here is my expression:

```
  var ignicoes = _context.Ignicoes
            .Where(e => (e.Estado == Ignicoes.EstadoIgnicao.emAvaliacao && (e.DataInicioPropostaIgnicao - dataAtual).TotalHours <= 12 ) ||
                    e.Estado == Ignicoes.EstadoIgnicao.aceite ||
                    (e.Estado == Ignicoes.EstadoIgnicao.concluido && (e.DataDecisaoIgnicao - dataAtual).TotalHours <= 12 ))
           .Include(i => i.ListaOcorrencias);
```

DataInicioPropostaIgnicao - is the date when it was posted to the database
dataAtual- is the current date of the system

I have class called Ignicoes, that has a property called Estado. Dependig on the Estado and how many hours the "Ignicao" has been posted to the database. I only want to return data that has been twelve hours or less in the database. Why am I having an error with this expression?
Here is the error:

[image]

I don't know if I made myself clear, but I hope someone can help me with this issue. Thank you

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Also, what are the types of the fields you are using in the query?

Comment: I'm using the default one in visual studio

Comment: The "Estado" is an enumerable, DataInicioPropostaIgnicao and dataAtual are both DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using EntityFramework you have to pay attention on how the Linq query is written: the query builder can't always translate the linq query to sql.

Based on this article https://entityframework.net/subtract-two-dates if you are using SQLServer the following should work:

```
int noOfHours = 12;
DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(noOfHours, 0, 0, 0));
var ignicoes = _context.Ignicoes
            .Where(e => (e.Estado == Ignicoes.EstadoIgnicao.emAvaliacao && e.DataInicioPropostaIgnicao >= oldDate ) ||
                    e.Estado == Ignicoes.EstadoIgnicao.aceite ||
                    (e.Estado == Ignicoes.EstadoIgnicao.concluido && e.DataDecisaoIgnicao >= oldDate ))
           .Include(i => i.ListaOcorrencias);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me because, if I have data that was posted  to the database yesterday at 12pm with Estado = emAvaliacao, it shouldn't appear because it pasted more than 12 hours. I don't know if that made sense

Comment: Yes. I want to make sure that the date when data was posted to the database when subtracted with today's date is equal or less than 12 hours difference

Comment: that's exactly what my code does, checks if the date is >= than 12 hours ago (oldDate is 12 hours ago from now)

Comment: Can please just explain this part?  DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(noOfHours, 0, 0, 0));

Comment: It means now - 12 hours.
If now is 13.00 of 7/7/2020, than oldDate is 01.00 of 7/7/2020

Comment: But in this code the variable oldDate returns 25-06-2020 meaning that it's substracting days instead of hours, how do I change it to hours?

Comment: I think I figured it out I just needed to change DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(noOfHours, 0, 0, 0));   with DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, noOfHours, 0, 0));